# Can I edit a custom library accessed through a URL?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am using the 'clibs' parameter in the URL to load a custom library into draw.io. Doing it this way prevents me from editing my own libraries i.e. I am unable to add or remove items. If I load the same library using "open library from GitHub", I am able to edit it. Can I not edit a library which has been opened using a URL?

Comment: You mean edit and save to somewhere other than the origin?